# I am unable to import airflow.operators.print_text_old from airflow

Tags: python, airflow

My command is

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

and the airflow was successfully installed but I am unable to import airflow.operators.print_text_old from airflow

The error message says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.print_text_old'

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.print_text_old import PrintText
```

The picture shows the error message

[image: Error message]

Hoe can I successfully import airflow.operators.print_text_old from airflow?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html) of Airflow 2.0:

> Importing operators, sensors, hooks added in plugins via
> airflow.{operators,sensors,hooks}.<plugin_name> is no longer
> supported, and these extensions should just be imported as regular
> python modules

You need to follow the [updating guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html#changes-to-airflow-plugins) to make your plugin compatible with Airflow 2.

Comment: hi can you please suggest me on how to type in from airflow.operators.print_text_old import PrintText in updated version @Elad